# How to Enforce outbound traffic of istio-enabled namespace over a consistent IP in IKS?

Tags: istio, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar, iks

I've my application deployed in istio-enabled namespace in IKS. I've egress-gateway service available in 'istio-system' namespace with external IP.how to enforce egress traffic over this external IP of egress-gateway for a istio-enabled namespace? is there any other way to achieve this?

'egress-gateway' is loadbbalancer kind service with external/public IP mentioned in it. How to ensure the outbound traffic is enforced on this IP?

sharing the destinationrule yaml which I applied for egress-gateway in istio-enabled namespace 'mynamespace'

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: egressgateway-destination
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  host: "*.svc.cluster.local"
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: DISABLE
  subsets:
  - name: egressgateway-subset
    labels:
      app: istio-egressgateway
```